# Send the .apk file to client for review

Tags: android, export, apk

I have developed an Android application and had it tested on emulator as well as device. I want to export the .apk file to the client for review. I used the Application manifest file to export the unsigned apk and sent it, but that's not getting installed on his phone.

I have read multiple questions over here but didn't get anything in specific to resolve my issue. I'm very new to this platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your client has allowed the installation of unsigned apks. On the droid, settings -> applications -> unknown sources check box.

Comment: I think "unknown source" is exact, not "unsigned apks".

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to to export your APK file.

First compile and run your app within Eclipse.
This will create the .APK file in your project folder.

The Path is usually
 Project Name\bin

You can copy that .APK file directly to your phone via a USB cable
Or you can email that to a client.

To install the APK file simple click on the file from a file manager application such as Root Explorer or File Manager.

The APK will automatically be installed once clicked.

Since the APK is not officially from the Google Playstore make sure the phone you are installing the app on has permission to install non-certified apps.

This can be enabled by going to
Settings-> Security-> Unknown Sources

Make sure that option is checked.  As you can see it says below
"Allow installation of non-Market apps

Answer (score 1):

Just make a key and sign the thing.