# How to send your .apk Glass Application for your client to see?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm jumping head first into Android for Google Glass development and I'd like to know how I can let my client see the .apk that I'm working on.

My client owns a pair of Google Glass too but lives far away.

So far, the only way I have been able to upload to Glass is using ADT, Run As -> Android Application when my Glass is connected by USB.

**How can I put the Glassware (apk) up online so he can "load it up" into his glass remotely? Or deploy it to his glass?**

I read [Send the .apk file to client for review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426350/send-the-apk-file-to-client-for-review) but it's more related to Android devices, whereas my client uses Google Glass and doesn't have debug mode on (I can ask him to turn it on though) and won't root his device.

Comment: https://testflightapp.com/android

Comment: I signed up to testflight app and have my client signed up too. Can you explain how I can get my apk onto his Glass please?

Comment: Hey can you try one thing.. Upload your APK to some server and send that URL to your clients Google Acount configured in Glass.

Comment: I will try that.. how would I direct glass to visit a URL? with QR code?

Comment: Yes I have tried that through QR code but its browser unable to download the APK. AFAIK the only option is what posted in answer.

Comment: My clients were unable to setup ADT, even with me assisting them on Skype - they need a simple a,b,c - 1,2,3 solution. Surgeons are simply  not the most tech savvy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have your customer use  ChromeADB  -- you can see it here:   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeadb/fhdoijgfljahinnpbolfdimpcfoicmnm/reviews?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

From the comments it looks like other people are using this for similar situations.

Comment: Thank you! this is the kind of easy answer I can get them to do.. tested the ChromeADB and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your client owns source code so they may be glad to download the SDK at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and install ADT then use the Android SDK Manager to install the SDK Platform, so they can either get your updated source and install it to Glass from ADT, or run adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb install .

Comment: No, he's got nothing setup.

Answer (score 0):

Well my client has the **Android SDK** installed on his system and he just turns on the **usb debugging mode on** on his glass. Then he installs the apk using the `adb install app.apk` command

Comment: That's the way I sideload apk's but my clients aren't comfortable with this approach unless I guide them to do it. I would rather a simple solution, like the gmail one (below) , I'm just waiting on my clients to confirm/deny that it worked.

Comment: I can confirm that there's no easier way than this right now. Your client will need to sideload the apk using adb.

Answer (score 0):

So far there is no other option available than this.

For Installation and testing on client side one need to follow below mentioned steps.

1. Download this [android-tools.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1764898&d=1361948659) to Windows PC and extract it using any unzip tool
2. Copy the desired APK file (Say testapp.apk) to the extracted folder i.e in android-tools
3. Now open command prompt `Win -> Run -> cmd -> ok`
4. Run this command `adb install testapp.apk`

Answer (score 0):

adb is open sourced, it shouldn't be difficult to wrap it up in a standalone application or you can rebuild adb and dependencies (due to binary license you can't simply redistribute you need to build the AOSP based code which is distributable - but IANAL)

If wrapping up commands (easier route) you can refer to these command line scripts to uninstall and run by simply passing the apk file name:

[How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools/17289998#17289998)

Answer (score -2):

Hopefully this helps...

But you could use [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) and have the client install the APK into the program. BlueStacks will setup a preference for ".apk" files to open up in the program itself, So no command line ADB is required. I dont know how well Glass APK's will run, however the BlueStacks emulator has come along way and work well with most general applications. So if your client has either Mac / Windows, they can easily setup an the Android emulator and can run your APK's. They could always just setup the Android SDK and use the standard emulator, It still will wont resemble a Glass device, however this could help the client understand what you are doing in the app. Its worth a try at least.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but my clients are surgeons and they want to see it on their Google Glass in the operating room.

Comment: @Loudparts I see... Well since they have Glass, then i would suggest Wireless or USB adb debugging, i mean once they have your latest APK they can run just a few ADB commands and simply install by `adb install folder/file.apk` in the command prompt and its installed. Its then locally stored on Glass for them to use until your next release.