# What's the easiest way a non-technical person and install an .apk on Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I need to deliver a GDK app I'm building.  Is instructing them to download the Android SDK and run adb commands the only way to side load the apps?  Is there any easier way for my non-technical colleagues?

Comment: I suppose you could write a small Windows application that automates that process. There wouldn't be all that much to it, and it might go a long way to make a client happy.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked a similar question and am in the process of trying it out. take a look at [How to send your .apk Glass Application for your client to see?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355024/how-to-send-your-apk-glass-application-for-your-client-to-see)

Comment: Not sure if they have figured it out yet, however.

Comment: Client is trying it out, I'm waiting on his response.. will comment as soon as I have more info